# reusing spring beans can cause nasty bugs when they are caching?

Tags: spring

Just finished a very long debug session. Please help me understand what root-cause/bad-practice caused this bug:

Beans A,B both had a property with an inner bean that looked exactly the same. Happily, I created bean C and reused it by doing `<bean ref="C">`.

However, bean C had a method called `"setX"` and a method called `"getLongComputationBasedOnX"`. Turns out that upon first call to this method, it lazily cached with a member variable the computation. Further calls to setX do not reset the cache.

So, after I tried to make the world a better place and reuse, the 2 uses of C in A and B each set a different value to X, but now it was a single instance and the cache gave the value appropriate to A when called in B... :(

Is this a spring issue? Should I use `parent` instead of `ref`? Or is it a bad design of my "setX" and it should reset the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `prototype` scope:

```
<bean id="C" scope="prototype"/>
```

This way you have a single `C` *declaration* but two *instances*, one created when injecting to `A` and another one for `B`.

In general it is hard to tell what the right design should be. Based on your explanation it seems like `C` was supposed to be used with only one `x` value. It should have been passed via constructor and made `final` to make this explicit though.

Otherwise you will get nasty concurrent errors: one thread calls `setX` and `getLongComputationBasedOnX` subsequently but in the meantime other thread called `setX`. That being said I believe my `prototype` solution is the right one.